# Bug problem? Or normal?

Tags: trees, lemons

I have an indoor lemon tree. Anyone know what this is ? They don’t wipe away? The tops my my leaves are turning a yellowish color.  Tree looks healthy overall.  I just don’t want anything to slip past me.

[image: Leaf with discolouration]